# Overflow hidden, display: table and border-radius in Internet Explorer(all versions)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

I have an image (represented by a green area in the example) that is supposed to be "masked" by a circle in the left side and vertically centered. It works as intended in Firefox and Chrome but not on any version of IE (tested IE 11 and Edge). On IE the corners of the image are shown, that is the part of the image supposed to be hidden by the border.

Here is the fiddle (test in Chrome for desired result):
http://jsfiddle.net/89j3mnj7/

```css
.left_circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
}
.image-mask {
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-right: 0;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_circle">
  <div class="image-mask">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using `display: table;`? If not then you can achieve similar functionality using `display: flex;` (minus the IE issue) http://jsfiddle.net/89j3mnj7/1/. If this is what you are after I would be happy to flesh this out into an answer.

Comment: it's something to do with how the `table` element is displayed in IE -- if you change the display to `block` or `inline-block` it does hide the overflow (but doesn't look how you want it to look -- this is not the solution unless you can move the green area down a little).

Comment: @freginold: Will I still be able to center the image then? I want the image to be vertically centered in the circle

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: I need support down to IE 9, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: I thought that may be a requirement, @Mike, there are other methods of vertically aligning content, I'll see if I can come up with another solution.

Comment: @Mike no, that would remove the vertical alignment.  Probably another way to do it, just would take more work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why is this happening?

Not entirely sure, if you push the element out of the container `overflow` is respected, however, the `overflow` does not appear to apply to the area cut off by `border-radius`. The issue only seems to occur when the `div`s are set to display like a table by using `display: table;`. This may not be a bug but an interpretation of the spec as Opera appears to function in the same way.

## How can it be fixed?

Removing `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` from `.image-mask` and `.image-container` will allow the `overflow` to work on the area cut off by `border-radius` but `.image` will lose the vertical alignment that `display: table;` provides. We will need to use another method to vertically align the element:

- Remove `.image-container` as it is no longer required
- Add `position: relative;` to `.image-mask`, this will allow `.image` to be positioned relatively to it
- Add `bottom: 0;`, `left: 0;`, `margin: auto 0;`, `position: absolute;` and `top: 0;` to `.image`, this will vertically center it in relation to `.image-mask.`

```css
.left_circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
}
.image-mask {
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_circle">
  <div class="image-mask">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above centering technique should work in IE9. If IE9 is not a requirement centering could be achieved by using flexbox:

```css
.left_circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
}
.image-mask {
  height: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}
.image {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_circle">
  <div class="image-mask">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.